# Is it possible to "explode" an array that contains multiple dictionaries using pandas or python?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to "explode" an array that contains multiple dictionaries using pandas or python?

I am developing a code that returns these two arrays (simplified version):

```
data_for_dataframe = ["single nucleotide variant", 
                     [{'assembly': 'GRCh38',
                       'start': '11016874',
                       'end': '11016874',
                       'ref': 'C',
                       'alt': 'T',
                       'risk_allele': 'T'},
                      {'assembly': 'GRCh37',
                       'start': '11076931',
                       'end': '11076931',
                       'ref': 'C',
                       'alt': 'T',
                       'risk_allele': 'T'}]]

columns = ["variant_type", "assemblies"]
```

So I created a pandas dataframe with using these two arrays - "data_for_dataframe" and "columns":

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data_for_dataframe, columns).transpose()
```

And the output was:

[image]

The type of the "variant_type" column is string and the type of the "assemblies" column is array. My question is whether it is possible, and if so, how, to "explode" the "assemblies" column and create a dataframe as shown in the following image:

[image]

Could you help me?

Comment: I believe there is a `df.explode` in Pandas. You can check it out

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that :) I was able to create the dataframe that way. Should I post here how I did it?

Comment: Yes, you can answer you own post :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with a combination of `apply()` and `explode()`.

```
exploded = df['assemblies'].explode().apply(pd.Series)
exploded['variant_type'] = df['variant_type']
```

**Output:**

```
assembly    start   end ref alt risk_allele variant_type
0   GRCh38  11016874    11016874    C   T   T   single nucleotide variant
0   GRCh37  11076931    11076931    C   T   T   single nucleotide variant
```